# Copy local svn repository to Assembla

Tags: svn, assembla

I'm using Visual SVN with drop box to version control my code. I've decided to move my repository to Assembla online. I can't for the life of me work out how to copy the repository I have on my dropbox to my Assembla URL.

I won't be needing to use Dropbox anymore all I want is to be able to access the repository from my new Assembla URL and commit/update from the URL.

Can anyone explain how I can do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it should depend on the way you created the svn repo,
if you created it by using `svnadmin create repo_name`, and this is the only way i know,
then you should be able to use `svnadmin dump repo_name > repo_name.dump` command as well,
later you can import your repo dump into an assembla subversion space.
usual import url for an svn assembla space is
http://app.assembla.com/code/space_name/subversion/repo

Comment: link now broken

Answer (score 2):

One of the issues with svn is that you can't turn a set of files into an svn repository in one operation.  You have to use a three step process:
1) "svn checkout" your new repository using your svn client and your repository URL.  In Visual SVN, the command is "Add Solution / Existing Repository".  You will get an empty "trunk" directory from the Assembla repository.
2) Copy the files into that directory
3) svn commit

I think it is a good idea to add a client operation to put non-versioned files into an existing repository, and I will ask for this from my svn client team.

Comment: I choose this answer, it's brief and clear, and it did good for me :)

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with dropbox, if it offers a way to get a backup then you can just import the backup to assembla easily on Import/Export tab of the Source/Svn tool(counting if you are familiar with assembla.com) and keep the commit history. If it does not offer backup then these are the steps you take if you want to commit a folder structure to svn.

```
1. create assembla space
2. add assembla svn tool, you will then get the svn-url looking like: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/<your-space-name>
3. svn clone https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/<your-space-name>
4. copy folder structure you want to add to svn as subfolders to <your-space-name>
5. add everything to svn (svn add <each folder>)
6. svn ci -m "initial commit"
```

Hope that helps